# Deleting 'Locked' Folders on the server

Tags: php, apache, file

I have an opencart folder on my server, and I want to delete it, however I can't because my FTP client simply say's:

> 550 shop_Opencart: Operation not permitted

I understand that some files have different permissions etc but why, as the server admin, can I not delete these files, or change the file permissions? Is there anything else that stops these files from being deleted or modified, other than file permissions?

Even using the control panel (in this case PLESK) I cannot delete them, I get a `Permission denied` error.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try chmod the folder using your ftp client and then delete it.

Comment: As stated, `Operation Not Permitted`

Comment: The folder is most likely owned by another user. You will need to delete it with that account or one with privileges.

Comment: I don't see how, I uploaded it, how can It be assigned to a different user?

Comment: This is most likely your problem http://www.uk-cheapest.co.uk/web-hosting/plesk-apache-file-permissions.php

Answer (score -1):

Connect via SSH using Putty as the root user and make the changes via that.